# Select datas FROM MS SQL Server 2005 through PDO with WHERE

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, character-encoding

I have this problem. I should select data FROM database (MS SQL Server 2005) using PDO. I have user class with functions.

```
public function select($sql, $array = array(), $fetchMode = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) 
        { 
            //try... if not catch exception 
            try{ 
              $sth = $this->DBH_->prepare($sql); 

              foreach ($array as $key => $value) { 
                $sth->bindValue("$key", $value);                    
              } 

              // run the query 
              $sth->execute(); 
              return $sth->fetchAll($fetchMode); 
            } 
            catch(PDOException $e) { 
                echo "<p class="error_msg">Ошибка. Свяжитесь с программистами.</p>"; 
                file_put_contents('errors.log', date("Y-m-d H:i:s")." - ".$e->getMessage().". File:".$e->getFile().". Line: ".$e->getLine()."\n", FILE_APPEND); 
                exit(); 
            } 

        }
```

When I use query with **WHERE** (string-Cyrillic), I don't get any result.

```
$authArr = $DBH->select("   SELECT 
                                        id_tip_tovar 
                                    FROM 
                                        skladskiy_uchet.dbo.spr_tip_tovar 
                                    WHERE 
                                        tip_tovar = N'Тип товар 1'");
```

How can I fix it?

P.S. Sorry, if I have grammar mistake. My english is not excellent.

Thanks...

Comment: When you run the same query in management studio, do you get results?

Comment: @Szymon, yes I get result

Answer (score 0):

You must set your FreeTDS protocol version higher than 4.2,  Because nvarchar columns were not introduced until sql server 2005 (or around there), they cannot be encoded into the protocol.  Edit /etc/freetds/freetds.conf

```
[global]
;tds version = 4.2
tds version = 7.2
```